# GoogleHadoopFileSystem class is missing when enabling TEZ

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We're running Hive on Hadoop leveraging Google Cloud Storage using bdutil version 1.3.2.  One of the options that we installed is TEZ.

> AMBARI_SERVICES='FALCON FLUME GANGLIA HBASE HDFS KAFKA KERBEROS MAPREDUCE2 NAGIOS OOZIE SLIDER SQOOP STORM TEZ YARN ZOOKEEPER KNOX HIVE PIG'

When running a query using the mapreduce query engine, everything runs as expected:

> set hive.execution.engine=mr;

But, if I change the execution engine to tez:

> set hive.execution.engine=tez;

I get a long stacktrace, but the error is:

> Status: Failed
>   Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 4, vertexId=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_00 [Map 4] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: t1 initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_00 [Map 4], java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found

I'm assuming that means that the gcs connector jar isn't in the right path, so I've added a link to the jar to the below paths, but still get the same error:

> /usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/hadoop/lib/gcs-connector-1.4.2-hadoop2.jar 
>   /usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/tez/lib/gcs-connector-1.4.2-hadoop2.jar 
>   /usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/tez/gcs-connector-1.4.2-hadoop2.jar 
>   /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/gcs-connector-1.4.2-hadoop2.jar

Any thoughts on what needs changed to enable tez?

Thanks for your help.

The full stack trace is:
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 4, vertexId=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_00 [Map 4] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: t1 initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_00 [Map 4], java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:130)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:245)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    ... 24 more
]
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 3, vertexId=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_01 [Map 3] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: t2 initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_01 [Map 3], java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:130)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:245)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    ... 24 more
]
Vertex killed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_02 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:null]
Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_03, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1443128249582_0182_1_03 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:null]
DAG failed due to vertex failure. failedVertices:2 killedVertices:2
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask